# How to input non-numpad numbers with Java Robot?

Tags: java, keyboard, numbers, keyevent, awtrobot

I'm running a Java robot class that I need to input the keyboard keys 0-9 (the actual numbers), but NOT the numpad numbers. For some reason, the java applet (which I did not write) that i am using does not accept the 0-9 key's from the numpad, only the 0-9 row above the standard keyboard. However, the Java robot class only seems to have a VK_NUMPAD# KeyEvent. At first, I tried the VK_1 event, but that turned out to have nothing to do with numbers (rather, the first 0-9 ASCII characters). Any way to get the top row of numbers? The robot I am using works fine other than that, and will happily input keys like "VK_P" and "VK_UP". 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us any information about the applet that you're using? Or the robot class that has the VK_NUMPAD# events?

Comment: The applet is http://www.webpacman.com/mspacman.htm . It will accept KeyEvents like VK_UP to move the pacman without complaint, just not the numbers. The robot class is the standard Java Robot from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html . Also, VK_NUMPAD[#] is just my notation for VK_NUMPAD1, VK_NUMPAD2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0) should be the definitive link for key codes.  When using `e.getKeyCode()`, we see that the codes for VK_NUMPAD are 96-105 for digits 0-9 respectively.  This is the case only if num_lock is on as you will get other codes if it is off.

Your attempt at VK_1 should have been correct.  That is code 49 which corresponds to the 1 on the top row having been pushed.  I tried this with an applet I had. I stuck in a KeyListener, and I verified that this is correct.  48-57 correspond to 0-9 on the top row which is listed in the link I gave as VK_0 ... VK_9.  There must be some sort of override (like the num_lock key overrides the number pad) that is remapping it because as I said VK_1 is the correct answer for the 1 character at the top of the keyboard.